# Limit on data transfer on TCP port between unix servers

Tags: networking, client-server, tcp

I don't have that much insight in networking.

I have two unix servers.I make a call through client to server using TCP connection.

It works fine with small data size.When I try to request data higher in size, API call dies abruptly.

So, just want to know is there any limit on the data transfer per request between unix servers ( clinet - server).If yes is there any way to increase it.

If there is limit I can take a help from my sysad to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance
Manish

Comment: What do you mean with size? The number of bytes written/read in a single call? Please show sample code.

Comment: And please define 'dies abruptly'. Symptom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such limit. TCP socket is a *bi-directional byte stream*, and it's up to the application how to split those bytes into messages (that's usually called "application-level protocol").

System administrator would not do anything for you here. You have to show us some code and explain the problem in a bit more detail before we can actually help you.